# Insert trigger to Update another table using PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, triggers

I have a table named awards. How can I mount a Trigger in PostgreSQL where each insert in the table awards updates a different table?

Comment: Could you provide some more details? Is this "different table" a single, separate table, or multiple tables based on some value of some field in awards.

Comment: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.1/static/triggers.html

Comment: @ertx Better to link to the /current/ doc instead of the /8.1/ doc, that's *extremely* out of date.

Comment: Didn't knew postgresql documentation had this feature, thanks, Craig

Comment: @ertx: [More about referencing the PostgreSQL manual on meta.SO.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/108714/169168)

Answer (score 84):

Here we have two tables named `table1` and `table2`. Using a trigger I'll update `table2` on insertion into `table1`.

**Create the tables**

```
CREATE TABLE table1
(
  id integer NOT NULL,
  name character varying,
  CONSTRAINT table1_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id)
)

CREATE TABLE table2
(
  id integer NOT NULL,
  name character varying
)
```

**The Trigger Function**

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION function_copy() RETURNS TRIGGER AS
$BODY$
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO
        table2(id,name)
        VALUES(new.id,new.name);

           RETURN new;
END;
$BODY$
language plpgsql;
```

**The Trigger**

```
CREATE TRIGGER trig_copy
     AFTER INSERT ON table1
     FOR EACH ROW
     EXECUTE PROCEDURE function_copy();
```

Comment: In the trigger Function how das it knows to insert values from table one? Don't we need to write "from table1" after "values(new.id, new.name)"?

Comment: new.id and new.name are the values from table1

Comment: Is the **nEw** stuff case-sensitive? Does `new` or `NEW` do?

Answer (score 6):

You want the [documenation for PL/PgSQL triggers](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-trigger.html), which discusses just this case among others. The general [documentation on triggers](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/triggers.html) may also be useful.

You can use either a `BEFORE` or `AFTER` trigger for this. I'd probably use an `AFTER` trigger so that my trigger saw the final version of the row being inserted, though. You want `FOR EACH ROW`, of course.

Comment: Hey @Craig Ringer is the purpose of FOR EACH ROW for batch inserts?

Comment: @rosenthal Huh? `FOR EACH STATEMENT` triggers don't have access to the `NEW` row. So even if you were doing a single row `INSERT` it wouldn't be useful for this.

Comment: I didn't mean that, pardon my poor choice in words. I mean what is the FOR EACH ROW do? I looked at the documentation for Postgres and understand it now. "A trigger that is marked FOR EACH ROW is called once for every row that the operation modifies. "