# How to create function that updates changes in one table from another table?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have this function that I found here:

[Insert trigger to Update another table using PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12343984/insert-trigger-to-update-another-table-using-postgresql)

```
CREATE TABLE table1
(
  id integer NOT NULL,
  name character varying,
  CONSTRAINT table1_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id)
)

CREATE TABLE table2
(
  id integer NOT NULL,
  name character varying
)
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION function_copy() RETURNS TRIGGER AS
$BODY$
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO
        table2(id,name)
        VALUES(new.id,new.name);

           RETURN new;
END;
$BODY$
language plpgsql;

CREATE TRIGGER trig_copy
     AFTER INSERT ON table1
     FOR EACH ROW
     EXECUTE PROCEDURE function_copy();
```

If I insert these two rows:

```
insert into table1 values (1, 'Andrey');
insert into table1 values (2, 'Mariza');
```

Then they also go into table2.

My problem is when I do an update on a value:

```
update table1 set name = 'Andi' where id = '1';
```

nothing happens in table2.

How can I create a function that updates changes in table?

Comment: I have one table that takes data from four different tables. I need the first table to be updated in case that the last four tables were actualized or chenged.

Comment: The value 'Andrey' is not changing into 'Andi'.

Comment: Why do you expect anything to happen when you run the `update` statement? Your trigger only fires for `insert` statements.

Comment: Is there anyway to make that trigger to work also on **UPDATE**?

Comment: Shalom Sagi, can u give me an example?

Comment: @AndreyRamnikov yes, just change it to : `AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE`. However note that you need to change your function code because you can not insert two rows with same key.

Comment: But i have to change also some code in function.

Comment: Why don't you make that table that takes data from four tables a view? That way you do not need to update anything. Or use table inheritance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To support `UPDATE` you can do this:

Trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER trig_copy
     AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE ON table1
     FOR EACH ROW
     EXECUTE PROCEDURE function_copy();
```

Function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION function_copy() RETURNS TRIGGER AS
$BODY$
BEGIN
    if TG_OP='INSERT' then
       INSERT INTO table2(id,name) VALUES(new.id,new.name);
    end if;
    if TG_OP='UPDATE' then
        Update table2 set name=new.name where id=old.id;
    end if;
    RETURN new;
END;
$BODY$
language plpgsql;
```

Comment: It Works but it's adds everything double. Is there a break command like in java?

Comment: @AndreyRamnikov post a sample of your current table data and an `Insert`/`Update` query which results in "double" rows.

Answer (score 0):

```
create or replace trigger trig_copy
  after insert or update
  on table1
begin
  merge into table2 t2
      using (
        select 
          id,
          name
        from
          table1 t1) t_new
        on (t2.id = t_new.id)
        when matched then
        update
        set
          t2.name = t_new.name
        where
          t2.id = t_new.id
        WHEN NOT MATCHED then
        insert (id,name) values(t_new.id,t_new.name);
end;
```

This will be applied to all records, not only updated record.

If U want to update/insert only one record Create trigger 
 referencing new as new
  for each row

and use :new.id :new.name , to find record You want in t2.

Comment: There is no `merge` statement in Postgres. And the syntax for the trigger is wrong as well. This looks like Oracle PL/SQL

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to all for help. This is the answer that had worked for me.
I took it from Elads and Justas solutions:

```
CREATE TRIGGER trig_copy
     AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE ON table1
     FOR EACH ROW
     EXECUTE PROCEDURE function_copy();

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION function_copy() RETURNS TRIGGER AS
$BODY$
BEGIN
if TG_OP='INSERT' then
    INSERT INTO table2
  (SELECT * FROM table1
   WHERE id NOT IN
       (SELECT id FROM table2));
   end if;
 if TG_OP='UPDATE' then
        Update table2 set name=new.name where id=old.id;
    end if;
    RETURN new;
end;
$BODY$
language plpgsql;
```