# Postgresql insert if does not exist

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have the following query

```
INSERT INTO address (house_number, street, city_id)
    values(11, 'test st', (select id from city where LOWER(city) = LOWER('somecity')))
```

Is there anyway to insert "somecity" in the `city` table if "somecity" does not exist in `city` then after inserting, it would return the ID for the inserted row?

I did find this answer that says upsert can be used to achieve this

https://stackoverflow.com/a/31742830/492015

but I can't find an example that inserts if select does not return the row.

Comment: The best option here would be using a trigger on address table that would do a lookup in the city and insert it if not present.

Comment: Another option would be to create a function that would do the lookup and whenever the city does not exists you insert it and return the id

Comment: Aaaaand to make this comments more fun: Nice job with the Night King! B)

Comment: You can create a *view* on the address table that takes the city name and a trigger on that view to accomplish what you want.

Comment: @JorgeCampos is there any example of using triggers to insert data into another table?

Comment: @Arya https://stackoverflow.com/a/24607012/460557

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of nesting the INSERTs, you could [use a CTE
to perform the INSERTs one after the other but as a single statement](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/48245/2037):

```
WITH tmp AS (
    INSERT INTO test_city (city) VALUES ('somecity')
    ON CONFLICT (lower(city)) DO UPDATE SET city = excluded.city
    RETURNING id, city
)
INSERT INTO test_address (house_number, street, city_id)
SELECT house_number, street, id
FROM (VALUES (11, 'test st', 'somecity')) val (house_number, street, city)
LEFT JOIN tmp USING (city)
RETURNING *
```

---

Using this setup:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS test_address;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS test_city;
CREATE TABLE test_address (
    house_number int
    , street text
    , city_id int
    );
CREATE TABLE test_city (
    id int GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY
    , city text 
    );
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX test_city_uniq_idx ON test_city USING btree (lower(city));
INSERT INTO test_city (city) VALUES ('Somecity');
```

and with the INSERT above, the query

```
SELECT * FROM test_address;
```

yields

```
| house_number | street  | city_id |
|--------------+---------+---------|
|           11 | test st |       1 |
```

and

```
SELECT * FROM test_city;
```

yields

```
| id | city     |
|----+----------|
|  1 | somecity |
```

---

Note that the CTE replaces

```
(select id from city where LOWER(city) = LOWER('somecity'))
```

with an INSERT .. ON CONFLICT .. DO UPDATE statement:

```
INSERT INTO test_city (city) VALUES ('somecity')
ON CONFLICT (lower(city)) DO UPDATE SET city = excluded.city
RETURNING id, city
```

I used `DO UPDATE` instead of `DO NOTHING` so that `RETURNING id, city` will always return something. If you use `DO NOTHING`, then nothing is returned when there is a conflict.

Note however that a consequence of using `city = excluded.city` is that the original `'Somecity'`
gets replaced by `'somecity'`. I'm not sure you'll find that behavior acceptable, but unfortunately I haven't figured out how to do nothing when there is a conflict and yet return `id` and `city` at the same time.

---

Another issue you may have with the above solution is that I used a unique index on `lower(city)`:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX test_city_uniq_idx ON test_city USING btree (lower(city));
```

This allows you to use the identical condition in the INSERT statement:

```
INSERT ... ON CONFLICT (lower(city))
```

as a substitute for the condition `LOWER(city) = LOWER('somecity')` which appeared in your SELECT statement. It produces the desired effect, but the trade-off is that now you have a unique index
on `(lower(city))`.

---

Regarding the [followup question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55912423/postgresql-insert-if-does-not-exist/55912999?noredirect=1#comment98506470_55912999)
of how to insert into more than 2 tables:

You can [chain together more than one CTE](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21387005/190597), and the subsequent CTEs can even reference the prior CTEs. For example,

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX city_uniq_idx ON city USING btree (lower(city));
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX state_uniq_idx ON state USING btree (lower(state_code));

WITH tmpcity AS 
(
   INSERT INTO
      city (city) 
   VALUES
      (
         'Miami'
      )
      ON CONFLICT (lower(city)) DO 
      UPDATE
      SET
         city = excluded.city RETURNING id, city
)
, tmpstate as 
(
   INSERT INTO
      state (state_code) 
   VALUES
      (
         'FL'
      )
      ON CONFLICT (lower(state_code)) DO 
      UPDATE
      SET
         state_code = excluded.state_code RETURNING id, state_code
)
INSERT INTO
   address (house_number, street, city_id, state_id) 
   SELECT
      house_number,
      street,
      tmpcity.id,
      tmpstate.id 
   FROM
      (
      VALUES
         (
            12,
            'fake st.',
            'Miami',
            'FL'
         )
      )
      val (house_number, street, city, state_code) 
      LEFT JOIN
         tmpcity USING (city) 
      LEFT JOIN
         tmpstate USING (state_code)
         ON CONFLICT (street) DO NOTHING
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I'm using your first example with CTE, it's working well, how would I add more tables like city to it? I also have a state table and a zipcode table.

Comment: You can [chain together more than one CTE](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21387005/190597), and the subsequent CTEs can even reference the prior CTEs.

Comment: This is what I constructed, something tells me I messed it up. https://pastebin.com/jejQ51di

Comment: I think you are almost there, except the VALUES tuple should repeat `'Miami', 'FL'`, and the join condition should be `LEFT JOIN tmpstate USING (state_code)`. I've edited post above to show what I mean.

Comment: Thanks, that works, but I ran into another complication when adding the CTE for the county table. Since there are cases where the same name for a county could belong to more than one state, I have to create an index on two columns for the county table. `CREATE UNIQUE INDEX county_uniq_idx ON county USING btree (lower(county), state_id);`  But `ON CONFLICT` only supports one column. I tried using ON CONFLICT ON CONSTRAINT shown here https://pastebin.com/BTd4hSZT, but unfortunately that does not work. What do you think is the best solution?

Comment: Nevermind, it looks like ON CONFLICT does support two columns

Comment: Another question if you don't mind. When chaining CTE, how do I access the id from the last CTE? for example https://pastebin.com/jdihGePs I'm using tmpstate.id to get the id, is that the correct way of doing it?

Comment: Use the [`INSERT .. SELECT .. FROM table` pattern](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/46477/2037),
where `table` is a `LEFT JOIN` between `VALUES` and `tmpstate`. Above, the last SQL example uses this pattern to insert `tmpcity.id` and `tmpstate.id`. An `INSERT` inside a CTE has exactly the same syntax as an `INSERT` outside a CTE.

Comment: What do you think if I use `citext` datatype instead of `text`? it's pretty much a case insensitive `text` datatype.